# Adding a new attribute to style

Tags: css

I have a slider and it works by loading in a background image. I need to resize this image so it fits to all screens i know what line of code i need to put in just dotn quite know how to go about it. I need to add

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

to the $style variable, how would i go about doing this.

I tried

```
$style = "background-size: 100% 100%;, background:url('". Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'] . "') 50% 0 no-repeat;";
```

But that loaded the background size but not the back ground.

```
<ul class="slides">
            <?php
            $slides = $this->getSlides();
            foreach($slides as $s) {
                $style = $content = '';
                $attr = 'data-img-height="0"';
                if ( !empty($s['image']) ) {
                    $imgSize = getimagesize(Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/'. $s['image']);
                    if ($imgSize) {
                        $style = "background:url('". Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'] . "') 50% 0 no-repeat;";
                        $attr = 'data-img-height="'.$imgSize[1].'"';
                    }
                }
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changing the code to

```
$style = "background:url('". Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'] . "') 50% 0 no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;";
```

That worked

Answer (score 0):

You will need to resize the image with the Magento function. You can't resize on the fly if it's a background image, plus it adds overhead.

If you are doing this for different viewports, you will need to add more logic and have different sizes loaded for each.